# Error when I try to redirect by http-equiv

Tags: php, redirect

Here is my code:

```
if ( $A=="3" ) {
<meta http-equiv="\refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://ex.com/"> 
}
```

Error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '<' in /home/ex/public_html/sy.php on line 94
```

What is the problem please?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is cleary indicated, you have a '<' (minor than) sign which happens all of a sudden, right after the opening bracket, and that's a syntax error. I think you meant:

```
if ( $A=="3" ) {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://ex.com">'; 
}
```

Or (if you're inside a "view" or similar):

```
<?php if ( $A=="3" ) {  ?>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://ex.com">; 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

With the way you are using it, your PHP will continue to execute and the page will not redirect until the HTML meta tag is executed by the client's browser. Maybe that's what you want it to do, but if not, this might be a better solution.

```
if ($A == "3")
    die(header("Location: http://ex.com/"));
```

Otherwise, as the other posters have already pointed out, you need to `echo`:

```
if ($A == "3")
    echo "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://ex.com/\">";
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that

```
<meta http-equiv="\refresh\" content=\"0; url=http://ex.com/">
```

is html. So you have to use an echo statement to print it out instead of just writing it like that/ So it should be

```
if ( $A=="3" ) {
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://ex.com">'; 
}
```